# How to append an object into a JSON array in perl?

Tags: json, perl

I tried to append the object into the json array but it ended up showing as a different format. I would be very grateful if anyone can show me the correct way.

Here is my code:

```
sub create_release_text_file
{

        my $result_path = shift;
        my %hshReleasebuild ;
        my @Releasebuild ;


        my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref;
        my $release_path =  File::Spec->catfile($result_path, "release.txt");


        $hshReleasebuild{"Build"} = $ARG_BUILD;         
        $hshReleasebuild{"Release"} = $ARG_RELEASE;

        push(@Releasebuild,\%hshReleasebuild);

        my $json_releasebuild = $json->encode(\@Releasebuild ); 




        open RELEASE_FILE, ">>", $release_path or die $!;   
        print RELEASE_FILE $json_releasebuild;
        close RELEASE_FILE; 


}
```

The result shows:

```
[{"Release":"11.0","Build":"135"}][{"Release":"12.0","Build":"120"}] ...
```

But the result I would like to get is:

```
[{"Release":"11.0","Build":"135"},{"Release":"12.0","Build":"120"}, ...]
```

Comment: So modify the contents of `@ReleaseBuild` before calling `$json->encode()`.

Comment: What version of `JSON` do you have?

Comment: @mob i'm using JSON -support_by_pp;

Comment: You're never going to get a correct result if you're opening the file for `>>`.

Comment: @AndyLester, can u show me the way? Thanks.

Comment: @AndyLester can u show me the way?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have the time to teach you the basics of Perl.  http://learn.perl.org has many fine resources.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the array represented in the JSON file, you'll need to actually obtain that array first!

```
my $json = do { local $/; <> };
my $releases = decode_json($json);
push @$releases, \%hshReleasebuild;
print encode_json($releases);
```

(Dealing with file handles other than STDIN and STDOUT left to you.)

Comment: Thanks ikegami, you're awesome!  Can you point me in the direction of, as I loop through each object, I want to append an additional key value pair?

Comment: @Spongekyle Hashpants, `$releases` is a reference to an array of references to "objects" (hashes), so `$_->{foo} = $bar for @$releases;`